# How to extract non nan values from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract n consecutive cells (without taking into account the non values) from a dataframe like the following:

[image]

We can have the following dataframes for n=2:

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Cool question but please provide the sample dataframes in a form where we don't have to type them in by hand.

Comment: Do you want all the solutions or just a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

```
>>> df 
     0    1     2   3
0  0.0  1.0   NaN  23
1  NaN  1.0  23.0   4
2  NaN  NaN   1.0   0
3  0.0  NaN   NaN   1
>>> df.apply(lambda s: s.dropna().iloc[:2].reset_index(drop=True), axis=1) 
     0     1
0  0.0   1.0
1  1.0  23.0
2  1.0   0.0
3  0.0   1.0
```

edit: this will give you the first two (or `n`) non missing values from each row. Your question is unclear on whether this is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your response.